# Node.JS Visual Studio 2013 and error with Q module on app startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2013

Very new to Node.JS and VS.
Using the simplest possible example, a console app, requiring Q:

```
var Q = require('q');

console.log('Hello world');
```

On launching this in VS an error is thrown on line 85 of q.js, no information is given in the error.  This error doesn't seem to be thrown when I launch outside of VS.
Any thoughts, why?  How to stop?